# Android - Extracting Data from Website

Tags: android, jsoup, httpurlconnection

I am going to create an app for android that is going to extract data from a website. Like the app is connected to let's say google.com and the user enters a keyword and clicks submit then the search results will be extracted and sent to the app. Any idea how I can do this? I've tried jsoup but I can't seem to connect it. I searched that there are others who are having trouble with .connect(url).get(). I also tried HttpURLConnection. What tool should I use? Thank you

Comment: Are you coding against an API? or are you wanting to 'scrape' a website?

Comment: I want to scrape data a website; extract its data. Get the data and put it to the app. Can you help me? thanks

Comment: Are you getting any specific error? There can be an issue of timeout.